# How to actually set "Use Config Settings"?

Tags: configuration, inventory, default

I've been searching high and low for this answer and hope someone knows.We just upgraded to 1.9.  Prior, our inventory was preset.

How does one set the "`Use Config Settings`" for inventory?

We would like to set it to default to Manage Stock to Yes.  We like to set `Minimum Qty to "1" and Maximum Quantity to "500"`.  Ideally, we would like to set everything to default to taxable goods.

If someone could steer us in the right directly, that would be awesome.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

- Navigate to Catalog > Manage Products
- Select all products, choose "Update Attributes"
- Select the Inventory tab, change accordingly

[image: Bulk Inventory Settings Screenshot]